# How can I generate a reliable digest from a hash in Ruby 2.4?

Tags: ruby, digest

I have a very large table containing 2 billion rows of 50 attributes. Not all are filled out and it's a sparse matrix.

I dislike having to build query off of all of the values, and the indexes are much too large now. I've lost performance.

For my new approach, I want to add a digest column that contains a digest of all of the attributes in a particular row.

There is no security requirement for this hash, so even MD5 would be fine.

Am I better off building a simple string containing representations of all the keys and values together? Or is there a better way?

For example, given hash:

```
attr_hash = { attribute1: "Please",
              attribute2: nil,
              attribute3: "don't",
              attribute4: nil,
              attribute5: nil,
              attribute6: nil,
              attribute7: "immediately",
              attribute8: "",
              attribute9: "downvote",
              attribute10: "my",
              attribute11: nil,
              attribute12: "question" }
```

would this be preferable (and I'm sure you'll agree this is beautiful):

```
attr_str = attr_hash.select{|k,v| v!="" && !v.nil?}.keys.sort.map{|k| "#{k}=#{attr_hash[k]}" }.join("^^")
digest = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(attr_str)
```

which gives a nice-looking string:

```
790470349a791b9897afd52a336ab2bb
```

I can index that column and get very, very fast response times from the database. And I'm unlikely to get many if any collisions from that. And if there's a collision one in 5 or 10 million times, it's fine.

I deeply appreciate any insights.

Comment: If the columns are in a predictable order, why not use an array instead of a hash?

Comment: The hash is returned from another method, and it's all text with some of it freeform. Since I'm excluding nil values I don't want a "yes" in one column to be confused with a yes from another column. If I just strung only the values together in an array I'd get dupes. But  essentially what I'm doing above is dynamically constructing an array with the keys AND values, then joining it together before creating the digest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lazy way:

```
Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(attr_hash.inspect)
```

Where that pre-supposes your items have identical ordering. If you need to sort the items first:

```
Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(attr_hash.to_a.sort_by { |k, _v| k }.inspect)
```

I'd use `JSON.dump(x)` instead of `x.inspect` if I wanted something more portable, like to non-Ruby code-bases.

I also wouldn't bother stripping out empty values. The hash function doesn't care.

Comment: ...and possible collisions are not a problem as one can easily weed-out interlopers with a secondary attribute-by-attribute check. What is your opinion of using `attr_hash.hash` instead?

Comment: Simply `hexdigest(attr_hash.sort.inspect)` would accomplish the same thing in this scenario.

Comment: Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(JSON.dump(attr_hash.to_a.sort_by { |k, _v| k })) Thanks tadman!

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful for somebody who is dealing with nested json object

```
def predigest_json(json)
  if json.class == Hash
    arr = []
    json.each { |key, value| arr << "#{predigest_json key}=>#{predigest_json value}" }
    json = arr
  end
  if json.class == Array
    str = ''
    json.map! { |value| predigest_json value }.sort!.each { |value| str << value }
  end
  if json.class != String
    json = json.to_s << json.class.to_s
  end
  json
end


Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(predigest_json(json))
```